# How to group by count of related records

Tags: mysql

I've two tables `invoices` and `products`.

```
invoices: store, 
products: id, invoice_id
```

I want to have a result set that shows how many invoices exists for each quantity of products.

I mean, if I have 2 invoices with 3 products each on store A, it will show `Store: A, Products qty: 3, Number of invoices (with three products): 2`

Another example:

```
| store | products_qty |    count   |
|   A   |      1       |      10    | 
|   A   |      2       |      7     |
|   A   |      5       |      12    |
|   B   |      5       |      12    |
```

Meaning, store A has 10 invoices with 1 product. 7 with 2 products, and 12 with 5 products...

I've tried with something like:

```
SELECT store, count(p.id), count(i.id) FROM invoices i
LEFT JOIN products p ON (p.invoice_id = i.id)
GROUP BY price, count(i.id)
```

however my group cause is not valid, it shows `Invalid use of group function`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: just `GROUP BY p.id`  - cuz You say: `store A has 10 invoices with 1 product. 7 with 2 products, and 12 with 5 products` then just group by product id and that's all.

Comment: that would give a row for each invoice, i want them grouped, i modified the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Being in love with no-sql technologies I would write aggregator processes that will catch insert/update/delete event and aggregate such information that You want in `store_statistics` collection. I think it will be better to do this also with mysql triggers ;)

Comment: I can do easily with a counter_cache column, but I was wonder how to do this in plain SQL and the answer didn't come easily to my mind :P

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do using subqueries, I wonder if is possible without it:

```
SELECT store, products_qty, count(*) FROM (
   SELECT store, count(p.id) as products_qty, count(i.id) as invoices_count 
   FROM invoices i
   LEFT JOIN products p ON (p.invoice_id = i.id)
   GROUP BY price, i.id
) AS temp GROUP BY store, products_qty;
```

Comment: I was going to write something like this (: